# Executor.submit not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Code Snippet :

```
//   MainClass 
public class DataStreamHandler {    
    Future<String> future =  executor.submit(new JobConsumer());                        
        try {               
            System.out.println("start future " );
            String str = (String) future.get();
          }
}    
//Thread Class
public class JobConsumer implements Callable 
{
   public String call() {
      //this logic listens to a stream and return.
      return "JobConsumer Done";
}
```

Here, after listening to the stream, only `call()` returns.

But now the main thread prints "start future" without `call()` finishing. How can I make sure that "start future" is printed only after `call()` is done?

Comment: This doesn't even compile.

Comment: Why would you expect "start future " to be printed after the task is complete? The whole point of submitting a task to an executor is so that it can run asynchronously, i.e., in parallel to the calling code. There's no guarantee which code will execute first between two threads. If you need it to print after the task is done, move it after the `get()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what does `future.get()` does and what does it actually returns?

Well, first it waits for the task to complete and returns the value returned by task's `call` method. In your case, `future.get()` will return `"JobConsumer Done"`.

After these two statements:

```
System.out.println("start future " );
String str = (String) future.get();
```

you can judge why *starts future* prints first.